# TFS build of Silverlight projects broken after upgrading to TFS 2013

Tags: msbuild, silverlight-5.0

I just upgraded TFS from 2012 to 2013 and the build definitions are no longer working.

We have some Silverlight 5 projects in our solution which are building fine on the dev machines and used to build on TFS 2012 as well, but now it fails. I have also installed VS 2013, Silverlight developer runtime and Silverlight 5 SDK.

The task which fails is ValidateXAML, here's a piece of the MSBuild log file:

> C:\Builds\4\path\to\project\Shared\PresentationUtility\Controls\AssetListControl.xaml : 
>   error : Cannot resolve reference assemblies. Please check the reference assemblies. Could not 
>   load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, ublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' 
>   or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> > Done executing task "ValidateXaml" -- FAILED. (TaskId:1514)
> >     Done building target "ValidateXaml" in project "PresentationUtility.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:2112)

Of course System.Core exists on the server in the right place with the right version, so I went after it with binding log viewer which gives me this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=unicode-1-1-utf-8"><!-- saved from url=(0015)assemblybinder: --><html><pre>
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (11/7/2013 @ 9:23:05 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\MSBuild.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Core, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MSBuild.exe
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Expression.Drawing, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\MSBuild.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Core, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v5.0/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v5.0/System.Core/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/System.Core/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Prototyping/Libraries/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Prototyping/Libraries/System.Core/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/RIA Services/v1.0/Libraries/Silverlight/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/RIA Services/v1.0/Libraries/Silverlight/System.Core/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/Client/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/Client/System.Core/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v5.0/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v5.0/System.Core/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/System.Core/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Prototyping/Libraries/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Prototyping/Libraries/System.Core/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/RIA Services/v1.0/Libraries/Silverlight/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/RIA Services/v1.0/Libraries/Silverlight/System.Core/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/Client/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/Client/System.Core/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/System.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/System.Core/System.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/System.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/System.Core/System.Core.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.


*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (11/7/2013 @ 9:23:05 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\MSBuild.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Core, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MSBuild.exe
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Expression.Drawing, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\MSBuild.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Core, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v5.0/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v5.0/System.Core/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/System.Core/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Prototyping/Libraries/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Prototyping/Libraries/System.Core/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/RIA Services/v1.0/Libraries/Silverlight/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/RIA Services/v1.0/Libraries/Silverlight/System.Core/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/Client/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/Client/System.Core/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v5.0/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v5.0/System.Core/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/System.Core/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Prototyping/Libraries/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Expression/Blend/Silverlight/v5.0/Prototyping/Libraries/System.Core/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/RIA Services/v1.0/Libraries/Silverlight/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/RIA Services/v1.0/Libraries/Silverlight/System.Core/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/Client/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Silverlight/v5.0/Libraries/Client/System.Core/System.Core.EXE, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/System.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/System.Core/System.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/System.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/System.Core/System.Core.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

</pre></html>
```

The key line is the first WRN:

```
WRN: Not probing location file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v5.0/System.Core.DLL, because the location falls outside of the appbase.
```

which is actually where System.Core is, but it says it's outside of the appbase.

I've never encountered something similar and my searches led me nowhere. Been chasing this for days now, does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the MSBuild platform to X86 in your build definition and it should solve your problem.

Hope it helps.